# Is it possible to get InstanceType<T> to work on an abstract class?

Tags: typescript

I obviously want to allow allow it to refer to implementations not the abstract itself, while still only relying on the abstract interface definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the type of the `prototype` instead of the type of the constructor return.

```
type AbstractInstanceType<T> = T extends { prototype: infer U } ? 
    U : never


abstract class Foo{
    foo:number
}

declare var foo: AbstractInstanceType<typeof Foo>;
foo.foo //ok
```

You might be better off using a constructor signature where you would have used `typeof AbstractClass`. `InstanceType` will work on this : `new (... a:any[]) => AbstractClass`

If you want to create a static factory method on an abstract class this is what will work :

```
abstract class Foo{
    foo: number
    static create<T extends Foo>(this: new () => T) {
        return new this();
    }

    static createWithArgs<T extends Foo, A extends any[]>(this: new (...a: A) => T, ...a: A) {
        return new this(...a);
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo { }
class Baz extends Foo {
    constructor(public n: string) {
        super();
    }
}

Bar.create()
Baz.createWithArgs("")
```

Comment: Great answers! Any idea how to make it work with a factory static method as well? This works to get the instance type as I want, which works on all my methods, but when I want to do new this() and I got this as T extends typeof AbstractClass it doesn't like me.


I tried adding a type guard with `if (this === ModelResource) throw new Error('cannot construct on abstract types');` at the start

Comment: @NathanielTucker edited the answer to add a static factory